# Is there an AD property that will tell me if an account uses ActiveSync?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003, activesync

I know that Exchange needs to hold onto sync status information for mailboxes, so I'm hoping I can use a related property to know who's using a smartphone to check mail.

We're still on Exchange 2003 so far.  It seems like the nicest method would be a saved query in ADUC, which I could hopefully use to create a distribution group?  But whatever you've got is better than what I have, so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can ask exchange if a user is using activesync. You need to find if Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync exists on that mailbox. You need to look for the  Glen Scales wrote a script to do just that.  [You can also parse the logs](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/02/14/419562.aspx). I couldn't find it on his site so here's the code:

```
servername = wscript.arguments(0)
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
strValueName = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias"
minTimeOffset = shell.regread(strValueName)
toffset = datediff("h",DateAdd("n", minTimeOffset, now()),now())

report = "<table border=""1"" width=""100%"">" & vbcrlf
report = report & "  <tr>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">DisplayName</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">Email Address</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">Device Type</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">Device ID</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">FolderSync</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">ContactSync</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">CalendarSync</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "<td align=""center"" bgcolor=""#000080""><b><font color=""#FFFFFF"">autdstate.xml</font></b></td>" & vbcrlf
report = report & "</tr>" & vbcrlf
set req = createobject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
set com = createobject("ADODB.Command")
set conn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Set iAdRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strNameingContext = iAdRootDSE.Get("configurationNamingContext")
strDefaultNamingContext = iAdRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
Conn.Open "ADs Provider"
polQuery = "<LDAP://" & strNameingContext &  ">;(&(objectCategory=msExchRecipientPolicy)(cn=Default Policy));distinguishedName,gatewayProxy;subtree"
svcQuery = "<LDAP://" & strNameingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)(cn=" & Servername & "));cn,name,legacyExchangeDN;subtree"
Com.ActiveConnection = Conn
Com.CommandText = polQuery
Set plRs = Com.Execute
while not plRs.eof
    for each adrobj in plrs.fields("gatewayProxy").value
        if instr(adrobj,"SMTP:") then dpDefaultpolicy = right(adrobj,(len(adrobj)-instr(adrobj,"@")))
    next
    plrs.movenext
wend
wscript.echo dpDefaultpolicy 
Com.CommandText = svcQuery
Set Rs = Com.Execute
while not rs.eof    
    GALQueryFilter =  "(&(&(&(& (mailnickname=*)(!msExchHideFromAddressLists=TRUE)(| (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(msExchHomeServerName=" & rs.fields("legacyExchangeDN") & ")) )))))"
    strQuery = "<LDAP://"  & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;" & GALQueryFilter & ";displayname,mail,distinguishedName,mailnickname,proxyaddresses;subtree"
    com.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    Com.CommandText = strQuery
    Set Rs1 = Com.Execute
    while not Rs1.eof
        falias = "http://" & servername & "/exadmin/admin/" & dpDefaultpolicy & "/mbx/"
        if not isnull(rs1.fields("proxyaddresses").value) then 
            for each paddress in rs1.fields("proxyaddresses").value
                if instr(paddress,"SMTP:") then falias = falias & replace(paddress,"SMTP:","")  & "/non_ipm_subtree"
            next
            wscript.echo  falias 
            SerachAsync(falias)
        else 
            wscript.echo "*** Null Proxy ****   : " & rs1.fields("mailnickname")
        end if
        rs1.movenext
    wend
    rs.movenext
wend
rs.close
set conn = nothing
set com = nothing
report = report & "</table>" & vbcrlf
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set wfile = fso.opentextfile("c:\temp\asreport.htm",2,true) 
wfile.write report
wfile.close
set wfile = nothing
set fso = nothing

wscript.echo "Done"

sub SerachAsync(furl)
strQuery = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D = ""DAV:"" >"
strQuery = strQuery & "<D:sql>SELECT ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/x3001001E"""
strQuery = strQuery & " FROM scope('shallow traversal of """
strQuery = strQuery & furl & """') Where ""DAV:ishidden"" = False AND ""DAV:isfolder"" = True AND "
strQuery = strQuery & """http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/x3001001E"" = 'Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync'</D:sql></D:searchrequest>"
req.open "SEARCH", furl, false
req.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
req.setRequestHeader "Translate","f"
on error resume next
req.send strQuery
if err.number <> 0 then wscript.echo err.description
on error goto 0
If req.status >= 500 Then
ElseIf req.status = 207 Then
    set oResponseDoc = req.responseXML
    set oNodeList = oResponseDoc.getElementsByTagName("d:x3001001E")
    if oNodeList.length <> 0 then
        wscript.echo "Active-Sync Folder Exists"
        displayAyncSub(furl & "/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync")
    else
        wscript.echo "No Active-Sync Folder"
    end if 
Else
End If

end sub

sub displayAyncSub(furl)

strQuery = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D = ""DAV:"" >"
strQuery = strQuery & "<D:sql>SELECT ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/x3001001E"""
strQuery = strQuery & " FROM scope('shallow traversal of """
strQuery = strQuery & furl & """') Where ""DAV:ishidden"" = False AND ""DAV:isfolder"" = True</D:sql></D:searchrequest>"
req.open "SEARCH", furl, false
req.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
req.setRequestHeader "Translate","f"
on error resume next
req.send strQuery
if err.number <> 0 then wscript.echo err.description
on error goto 0
If req.status >= 500 Then
ElseIf req.status = 207 Then
    set oResponseDoc = req.responseXML
    set oNodeList = oResponseDoc.getElementsByTagName("d:x3001001E")
    for each node in oNodeList
        call displaydeviceSub(furl & "/" & node.text,node.text)
    next
Else
End If
end sub

sub displaydeviceSub(furl,fname)

strQuery = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D = ""DAV:"" >"
strQuery = strQuery & "<D:sql>SELECT ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/x3001001E"""
strQuery = strQuery & " FROM scope('shallow traversal of """
strQuery = strQuery & furl & """') Where ""DAV:ishidden"" = False AND ""DAV:isfolder"" = True</D:sql></D:searchrequest>"
req.open "SEARCH", furl, false
req.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
req.setRequestHeader "Translate","f"
on error resume next
req.send strQuery
if err.number <> 0 then wscript.echo err.description
on error goto 0
If req.status >= 500 Then
ElseIf req.status = 207 Then
    set oResponseDoc = req.responseXML
    set oNodeList = oResponseDoc.getElementsByTagName("d:x3001001E")
    for each node in oNodeList
        report = report & "<tr>" & vbcrlf
        report = report & "<td align=""center"">" & rs1.fields("displayname") & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
        report = report & "<td align=""center"">" & rs1.fields("mail") & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
        report = report & "<td align=""center"">" & fname & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
        report = report & "<td align=""center"">" & node.text  & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
        report = report & finditems(furl & "/" & node.text)
        report = report & "</tr>" & vbcrlf
    next
Else
End If
end sub

function finditems(furl)

hascalsyc = 0
hasfolsyc = 0
hasconsyc = 0
hasautd = 0
rback = ""
strQuery = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D = ""DAV:"" >"
strQuery = strQuery & "<D:sql>SELECT ""DAV:displayname"", ""DAV:getlastmodified"""
strQuery = strQuery & " FROM scope('shallow traversal of """
strQuery = strQuery & furl & """') Where ""DAV:isfolder"" = False</D:sql></D:searchrequest>"
req.open "SEARCH", furl, false
req.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
req.setRequestHeader "Translate","f"
on error resume next
req.send strQuery
if err.number <> 0 then wscript.echo err.description
on error goto 0
rem wscript.echo req.responsetext
If req.status >= 500 Then
ElseIf req.status = 207 Then
    set oResponseDoc = req.responseXML
    set oNodeList = oResponseDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:displayname")
    set oNodemodlist = oResponseDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:getlastmodified")
    wscript.echo oNodeList.length
    for i = 1 to oNodeList.length
        set onode = oNodeList.nextNode
        set onode1 = oNodemodlist.nextNode
        select case lcase(onode.text)
            case "calendarsyncfile" hascalsyc = 1
                        hascalsycval = DateAdd("h",toffset,(left(replace(replace(onode1.text,"T"," "),"Z",""),19)))
            case "foldersyncfile"   hasfolsyc = 1
                        hasfolsycval = DateAdd("h",toffset,(left(replace(replace(onode1.text,"T"," "),"Z",""),19)))
            case "contactssyncfile" hasconsyc = 1
                        hasconsycval = DateAdd("h",toffset,(left(replace(replace(onode1.text,"T"," "),"Z",""),19)))
            case "autdstate.xml"    hasautd = 1
                        hasautdval = DateAdd("h",toffset,(left(replace(replace(onode1.text,"T"," "),"Z",""),19)))
        end select
    next
Else
End If
wscript.echo hasfolsyc
if hasfolsyc = 1  then
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">" & hasfolsycval & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
else
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">No&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
end if
if hasconsyc  = 1  then
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">" & hasconsycval & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
else
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">No&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
end if
if hascalsyc  <> 0  then
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">" & hascalsycval & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
else
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">No&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
end if
if hasautd  <> 0  then
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">" & hasautdval & "&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
else
    rback = rback & "<td align=""center"">No&nbsp;</td>" & vbcrlf
end if
finditems = rback
end function
```

Comment: Hmm... that might just do it to find out which users have used ActiveSync, such that you can set the appropriate property in AD. I hadn't thought of grovelling thru the MDB like that using DAV. That's pretty ingenious. The formatting on that script makes my eyes bleed, but it looks like it would do the trick.

Comment: yeah I couldn't figure a way to format it better- it looks alot better in notepad on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's controlled by one of the bits in msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable.  Here's the bit description listed by someone in [**this post**](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/windows-server-active-directory/t-msexchomaadminwirelessenable-values-522132.html).

```
1 (bit 0) = 1 to disable Server Activesync, 0 to enable it
2 (bit 1) = 1 to disable OMA, 0 to enable it
4 (bit 2) = 1 to disable Always Up-To-Date (AUTD), 0 to enbable it
```

Looks like the value is a decimal value in AD so you'd need to AND the bits together and convert that to decimal to set it.  Thus:

```
Disable everything = 0x111 = 7
Enable ActiveSync, Disable OMA, Disable AUTD = 0x110 = 6
Enable ActiveSync, Disable OMA, Enable Autd = 0x010 = 4
etc...
```

Comment: Yep-- but by default this isn't set on any users, so Exchange 2003 assumes a default of "0" and allows all users access. In the poster's environment, assuming a stock Exchange 2003 deployment, he's not going to find this attribute anywhere on users in his AD.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this first: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830188

So, basically, the "msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable" attribute isn't set on all user objects by default, and access using ActiveSync is allowed. If you elect to turn it off for all users, and then enable it only for the users who require it, then you can filter / query on this "msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable" attribute.

So, it's a chicken and egg problem. If you don't know who is using it, you can't change this attribute.

I'd consider parsing the logs on your IIS server to determine who is using ActiveSync, then consider setting the flag on all users who are not using it. It's painful, but it looks like the best way I can see to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through all the attributes and could not find anything that would be a giveaway.

Sorry.